# heatmap like plot with different sets of colors for different data

Tags: r, plot, pheatmap

I'm trying to join different type of data in the same heatmap plot. But I need to use different set of colors for each of the sub-data.
Here is an example:

```
data1 = matrix(c(1:9),nrow=3)
color1 = colorRampPalette(c('red','blue'))(max(data1))
data2 = matrix(sample(c(0:1),12, replace=T),nrow=3)
color2 = colorRampPalette(c('black','white'))(max(data2)+1) # +1 because it starts in 0
data = cbind(data1,data2)
# I want to join the following two images
image(t(data1),col=color1)
image(t(data2),col=color2)
```

The result should have the first 3 columns (from data1) in colors red/blue, and from the 4th to the end columns should be in black/white.
I can transform data matrix into a colors matix if this helps. I tried heatmap(), but seem to work with just one set of colors. 
In the example, the 1 from data1 should be plotted red, but from the data2 should be plotted white.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the same color index twice. However, you can work around this by adding a suitable offset to the elements of `data2` and concatenate the data and colors as follows:

```
image(t(cbind(data1,data2+length(data1)+1)), col=c(color1, color2))
```

Comment: You're welcome! And it'd be nice if you'd mark this answer as having solved the issue. :)